# Create Row number in Excel Source Task

Tags: ssis

I got an excel file for pulling data to SQL Server DB. At Excel Source, I wanted to create ROW_NUMBER() like in T-SQL, as an additional column. Is it possible in EXcel Source query ? How ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using a script component: [Generating Surrogate Keys](http://sqlis.com/post/Generating-Surrogate-Keys.aspx)

or you can download a custom component that does that for you. There are a few, but the downsize of this option is that you have to deal with the deployment of this component (which is simple, just copy the dll, but is one more thing to worry about)